# getting direction of x and y... north,south,east,west

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

I have a player in the center of the screen, where I also have my mouse position origin. (0,0)  I would like to know the direction of the mouse, imagine splitting the screen with a  X, so the top quadrant would be north, the bottom would be south... and so on. So if my mouse was at 5,-100 it should log ("North")  as that is just a bit to the left and up 100 pixels.

Comment: Come on people. This is a valid question, even though it's simple. Explain your down votes if you're going to down vote.

Comment: Without the accepted answer it is difficult to understand exactly what is being asked. This question reads more like a statement. Since this site strives to be a knowledge base for future users consider rephrasing as a clearer question.

Comment: -1 Severe lack of research

Comment: I would say this question which reads as how to track the mouse direction so I can find if I move north, south, east and west. It is pretty hard to google for that, atleast I fail to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (Abs(Y) > Abs(x)) {
  if (Y < 0) {
    return "North";
  } else {
    return "South";
  }
} else {
  if (X < 0) {
    return "West";
  } else {
    return "East";
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought for sure some trig would be needed, I guess not!

Comment: Might want a slight amendment to the code to handle the `X == Y == 0` case.